# Asynchronous REST client

Tags: java, spring, rest, asynchronous, resttemplate

How to write **asynchronous** REST client?

My *controller* (not sure if it's enough for being *async*):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get/all")
@ResponseBody
public Callable < CustomersListDTO > getAllCustomers() {
    return new Callable < CustomersListDTO > () {

        @Override
        public CustomersListDTO call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return customerService.getAllCustomers();
        }

    };
}
```

My synchronous REST *client* method:

```
public Response get_all_customers() {
    ResponseEntity < CustomersListDTO > response;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
            getMethodURI(ServiceExplanation.GET_ALL_CUSTOMERS),
            CustomersListDTO.class
        );
        message = "Customers obtained successfully!";
    } catch (HttpServerErrorException ex) {
        message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage() + " - " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage() + " - " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (RestClientException ex) {
        message = checkIfServerOrInternetDown();
    }

    return formResponse(message, response);
}
```

How do I make it *asynchronous*? How can the CLIENT continue doing other tasks while SERVER is obtaining data and later return found data?

Comment: Read about concurrency. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: look at the following link https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for REST asynchronous client implementation, you can take a look at Jersey's [asynchronous client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e8611). It can be easily integrated with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding support for groovy in your application so you can use AsyncHTTPBuilder which is what you are trying to do. It basically uses FutureTask under the cover.

Answer (score 0):

Check Ning' async http client： https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

also eBay' REST commander for parallel rest async client ready to use: http://www.restcommander.com/